# Как добавить класс элементу после проверки его содержимого?

Tags: jquery

Нужно добавить класс к `<div>` после сравнения его содержимого с заданной строкой:

```js
if ($('#orders .order :last-child').text() === 'Z' ) {
    console.log('green');
    $(this).addClass('green'); //тут проблема
}
```

```css
.order {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='orders'>
    <div class='order'>
        <div class='b1'>X</div>
        <div class='b2'>Y</div>
        <div class='b3'>Z</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не стоит вставлять ключевые слова в заголовок вопроса, если они не имеют к нему прямого отношения: для этого есть теги.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что $(this) в момент выполнения ссылается вовсе не на нужный div, ведь это не обработчик события, к которому jQuery автоматически привязывает контекст, а просто проверка. Поэтому вам нужно сохранить найденный элемент в переменную и работать с ней:

```
var $myEl = $('#orders .order :last-child');

if ($myEl.text() === 'Z') {
  $myEl.addClass('green');
}
```

Comment: А если несколько таких div

Comment: Значит, нужно использовать .each() и вот там $(this) будет ссылаться на обрабатываемый элемент. https://jsfiddle.net/alexey_m_ukolov/7n839hc3/

Comment: Алексей, не могли бы вы пример с each() привести